# "Stone of Folly" based on maybe finding and removing brain tumors?

Tags: biology, medicine, middle-ages

There is a famous [painting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_the_Stone) by [Hieronymus Bosch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hieronymus_Bosch) in which someone is being operated on to remove the "[stone of folly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_of_madness)".

> [image]
> Detail from Hieronymus Bosch's painting titled "Extraction of the Stone of Folly". It depicts a surgeon, who is wearing a funnel hat and is cutting into the skull of a patient by [trepanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trepanning).

My question is whether *all* of the following is possible:

- someone exhibits cognitive difficulties due to pressure from a tumor, perhaps one so large that it deformed the skull (not sure if that can happen);
- this suggested that cutting into the head might be indicated, and
- assuming the patient did not die, perhaps sometimes some improvement was indeed observed because the pressure was relieved.

Comment: Trepanning wasn't used just for brain tumours, but also for when they thought a man or woman was possessed. Nowadays we would say they had mental health issue's such as bipolar, depression, schizophrenia or psychosis and the like.

Answer (score 4):

[Trephination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trepanation) has an ancient history.  In the right hands, it may have been a useful tool to deal with depressed skull fractures and subdural hematomas.  Many of the patients *did* survive, rather amazingly when one considers it is at least nominally brain surgery done in 6500 B.C.  (Also note that many ancient cultures, armed with opium, nightshade, cannabis, and more dubious agents, were more skilled with anaesthesia than witch-fearing Medieval Europe)

A subdural hematoma is a somewhat solid object (which is to say, clotted blood) not otherwise found in the body, which can cause strange symptoms (Richard Feynman told a great story - [here's one version](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1986-04-20-tm-1265-story.html)).  You can see from [this set of images of a modern trephination](https://www.dovepress.com/cr_data/article_fulltext/s193000/193548/img/ndt-193548-f01.jpg) that the operation essentially consists of the removal of a solid, unwanted body (panel E) that could cause behavioral symptoms.  One can argue this way it *ought* to have been counted as a "stone of madness", but proving that point historically is another matter.

Comment: i found feynman's story, really does not go into the idea that "stones" were solid tumors or something else that resembled stones.

Comment: I've linked to an image of one of these operations - the hematoma is obviously *squishier* than your average stone, but it presents the appearance of a strange, unwanted, more or less solid body, more so I think than a tumor would.  And hematomas really *can* be removed successfully be trephination, even with ancient technology.

Comment: i may summon up the courage to look at it at some point.

Comment: i am wondering if the feyman story has anything to do with stan ulam who got some kind of brain infection which was treated with direct application of penicillin to the brain tissue -- his life and intellect were saved; this was in mid 1940s and a few years earlier the outcome would have been grim almost certainly.

Comment: I added one account I found - it isn't as nicely written as what I recall reading long ago, but it gets something of the idea across.  (This is a description of odd behavior, not the clot itself)